# JkMount Ignoring Alias

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I am setting up a new server using Apache, Tomcat and Railo ColdFusion.  I am using mod_jk to connect Apache to Tomcat, and am using a CMS system on the java server.  I want to forward every request to the Tomcat server except for a specific directory of files, because of the way the CMS works.

So I setup my JkMount in my site config like the following

```
JkMount /* ajp13w
```

This works just fine, but I want to now add an ignore for a directory which is actually an Alias.  I tried add this line:

```
Alias /store /websites/eac/www/store
JkMount !/store ajp13w
```

But that won't work.  Is there a way to forward all files, except /store to the Tomcat server with mod_jk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
JkUnMount /store/* ajp13w
```